# How do I find a cluster of POIs that contain all POIs that user selected (within a specified radius)?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, graph-algorithm

I apologize for the convoluted title. Needless to say, I am running out of search keywords but haven't found anything I could study on the subject.

I am building a system where a user selects multiple POI criteria (checkboxes showing "restaurant", "gas station", etc). I then want to return a location on a map that is within x distance of every POI the user selected.

Assuming I have the information of every POI on the map, what would the algorithm be to find a cluster of points that contain all specified points?

An abstracted way to describe this is:
Say I have several sets of grid points.
What could be the algorithm to find a circle of radius r (fixed) on the grid that contains at least one point from each set?

I would appreciate any help or pointers that I can follow.

Comment: Is there a maximum limit on no. of POIs? And Is x constant? By point you mean frid point. right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. X is a constant. There is a limit on maximum number of POIs. And yes, grid points was what I meant.

Comment: by location, you meant any grid point satisfying that criteria. right?

Comment: Yes. I am looking to return a point in the grid that is a center of a fixed radius circle. The circle will contain all points of interest selected by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using gradient decent method. Let n be the number of POI(points) a user has selected. Idea is to keep decending towards the point closest to all the n points.

```
ita = 0.01; //learning rate.
i=0 ;    // weight decay rate
First start with the mean point p(x,y) of all the points.
while (p is not within from each point || no improvement in p during last iteration).
    let q(x,y) be the farthest point from p.
    update: p(x,y)+= ita*(q(x,y)-p(x,y))/(i*n*x)
return p if exist else NULL if timeout happens.
```

Is this what you want. This algorithm solves your problem. If you think the point closest to all n points will be better contender, you can modify it as well.

see this as well, [The "All-Pairs Closest Points" Problem](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/the-all-pairs-closest-points-problem/184405252?pgno=1).